# libUSB / WinUSB to WinDDK Driver Port

Tags: windows, device-driver, libusb, wdk, winusb

I want to port libUSB driver to the windows driver using WDK (In Kernel Mode).
I found that libUSB internally uses the winUSB ( From libUSB Sources).

This is what I do in the libusb,

1. I get the handle using, libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid

   or libusb internally uses pSetupDiGetClassDevsA and other pSetupDi*** functions
2. I send the data using libusb_control_transfer or internally WinUSB's WinUsb_WritePipe

What are the equivalent functions of this in WDK in Kernel mode?
Is there any sample that I can use?

**NOTE:**
The reason I am asking for kernel mode is, I need to take this data and re-route it as HID Mini Driver.

Comment: You should read about WDM drivers. It is a totally different story doing this in kernel mode. There is a sample in winddk called usbsamp. I suggest you to start there.

Comment: I found the usbsamp http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
But, it is a full fledged driver exposed to application.
I am looking for something simpler.

Thanks for pointing, you can post this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about WDM drivers. It is a totally different story doing this in kernel mode. There is a sample in winddk called usbsamp. I suggest you to start there.

for easier approches, you may want to look at KMDF : read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463311.aspx